# returning argument missing error even after passing a dataframe

Tags: r

I am writing a function to return the variable name and class in a `data.frame`.

```
vec_name<-c()
vec_class<-c()
Df_class <- function(x){
    for (i in 1:length(colnames(x))){
        vec_name[i] <- colnames(x)[i]
        vec_class[i] <- class(colnames(x)[i])
    }
    df <-as.data.frame(name=vec_name,class=vec_class)
    return(df)
}
```

Now when I call the function

```
Df_class(mtcars)
```

I see an error mentioned below

> Error: argument "x" is missing with no default

Can you guys help? May be I am missing something here not sure what! Why am I getting an error despite of passing a `data.frame`?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do. Can you provide some details and include your expected output for e.g. `mtcars`?

Comment: Change your `as.data.frame` line to `df <- data.frame(name=vec_name,class=vec_class)` and it should work.

Comment: Moreover, I think you just need `data.frame(name = names(mtcars), class = sapply(mtcars, class))`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do. For example, the `class` of existing column names will always be `"character"`.

Either way, is this what you're after?

```
Df_class <- function(x) data.frame(name = colnames(x), class = class(colnames(x)))
#   name     class
#1   mpg character
#2   cyl character
#3  disp character
#4    hp character
#5  drat character
#6    wt character
#7  qsec character
#8    vs character
#9    am character
#10 gear character
#11 carb character
```

Perhaps you'd like to return the `class` of the *column vector* instead of the column name? In this case, you can do

```
Df_class <- function(x) data.frame(name = colnames(x), class = sapply(x, class))
Df_class(iris)
#                     name   class
#Sepal.Length Sepal.Length numeric
#Sepal.Width   Sepal.Width numeric
#Petal.Length Petal.Length numeric
#Petal.Width   Petal.Width numeric
#Species           Species  factor
```

Comment: thank you so much. am looking for the later one. I realised the "class" will be always a character that after posting . This is perfect. Do you also know why am getting an error inspite of sending an argument for "x"

Comment: Never mind, i figured it out. The issue is with declaring the dataframe.i was using as.data.frame instead of data.frame  > Df_class <- function(x){
+     for (i in 1:length(colnames(x))){
+         vec_name[i] <- colnames(x)[i]
+         vec_class[i] <- class(x[,i])
+     }
+     df <-data.frame(name=vec_name,class=vec_class)
+     return(df)
+ }

Comment: Great and you’re very welcome @user10103663. Btw, you really don’t need the `for` loop here. But I assume this is part of a bigger exercise.